# ASP.NET MVC3 route for static .cshtml files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm adding some .cshtml files with some content (nothing dynamicaly loaded, just a static content)

There are several files:
/Views is a directory
/Dealership is a directory in /Views

```
Views - Dealership - About.cshtml
Views - Dealership - Testimonials.cshtml
Views - Dealership - Audi.cshtml
Views - Dealership - AudiA6.cshtml
Views - Dealership - AudiA8.cshtml
Views - Dealership - BMW.cshtml
Views - Dealership - BMW5.cshtml
Views - Dealership - BMW7.cshtml
```

Urls should be:

```
www.mywebsite.com/dealership/about
www.mywebsite.com/dealership/testimonials
www.mywebsite.com/dealership/audi
www.mywebsite.com/dealership/audi/audi-A6
www.mywebsite.com/dealership/audi/audi-A8
www.mywebsite.com/dealership/bmw
www.mywebsite.com/dealership/bmw/bmw-5
```

How the route should look like? I have this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Dealership", // Route name
        "dealership/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Dealership", action = "Index", id = string.Empty }); // Parameter defaults
```

It works for

`www.mywebsite.com/dealership/audi`

or

`www.mywebsite.com/dealership/testimonials`

but I don't know how to create the route for

`www.mywebsite.com/dealership/audi/audi-A6`

I hope it's not too confusing ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally static content should go in the Content directory, but I can see why you don't want to do that.  I would consider using partial views for the specific vehicles, then using logic in the base view for that manufacturer to determine whether to show the generic code or the partial for a particular view based on the model.  In your controller, add another parameter for the car model (note, I've renamed `id` to `make`).

Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Dealership", // Route name
        "dealership/{action}/{make}/{model}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Dealership", action = "Index", make = string.Empty , model = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index( string make, string model )
{
     return( make, model );
}
```

Views (audi.cshtml)

```
 @model string
 @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model)) {
    .. manufacturer html...
 }
 else
 {
    @Html.Partial( "audi-" + Model );
 }
```

Then have your view folder structured like

```
 dealership/audi.cshtml
 dealership/audi-audi-a6.cshtml
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not working beacuse the framework search for a view with "audi-A6" name, but it doesn't exist. It's name is "audiA6".
Try to change the view name in "audi-A6.cshtml".

I hope it's helpful

Comment: That is not true, right now the framework is thinking that audi-a6 is a parameter, the route knows nothing of views, it only knows which controller, action and route parameters are, nothing else, the Action knows which view to present to the user.

Comment: The problem is that www.mywebsite.com/dealership/audi route always wins, even if I use www.mywebsite.com/dealership/audi/audiA6

Comment: @Joakim True, I haven't seen Audi/Audi-A6, sorry